# using contents of an array as a parameter for foreach loop

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I'm trying to update the fields on my database with the ff code:

```
<?php 

session_start();

include ('../../class/connection.php');

$sql = "UPDATE reservationmenutable SET service = ? WHERE id = ?";
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);

foreach ($_POST["hidden_id"] as $key => $db_id) {

    foreach ($_POST["service_id"] as $key => $service_key) {
    $statement->execute([$service_key, $db_id ]);

    }

}

?>
```

the POST values are arrays so I had to loop them to get to them one by one right, but I'm confused on how to do it.

I'm trying to use the contents of hidden_id[] for the second loop. I thought about using a variable then increment it one by one but that would not match since each service has a corresponding id on database, ideas would appreciated. thanks :)

Comment: If you want multiple update, you have to put the UPDATE on the loop

Comment: you have to make sure both arrays are properly lined up first, then bind and execute on a loop

Comment: I forgot to include that hidden_id[] actually have values on the form, im trying to access the content of hidden_id[] so that i can use it on: $statement->execute([$service_key, "contents of hidden_id" ]); BUT MY LOGIC might be wrong

Answer (score 0):

Just use the $key ot hidder_id as the index of service_id

hope it helps

```
$serviceKeys = array_keys($_POST["service_id"]);
foreach ($_POST["hidden_id"] as $key => $db_id) {
    $statement->execute([$serviceKeys[$key], $db_id ]);

}
```

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work.. I forgot to include that hidden_id[] actually have values on the form, im trying to access the content of hidden_id[] so that i can use it on: $statement->execute([$service_key, "contents of hidden_id" ]);

Comment: @skerkro check it

Comment: PDOStatement::execute() expects at most 1 parameter, 2 given

Comment: they're both arrays.. and btw thanks for the effort pal

Comment: @skerkro I lost a [, I 've modify it